# Guice binding based on annotation value

Tags: java, guice

My usecase is something like this. My system has already has a configuration system, where we add configuration in a text file, similar to properties file but not exactly. I want to reuse the same configuration system. The configuration system provides this interface:

```
public interface ConfigurationProvider {
   Boolean getBoolean(String key);
   String getString(String key);
   Long getLong(String key);
   ...
}
```

I want to use @Named annotation to get the configuration values injected, something like:

```
public ClassA {
   String stringVal;
   Long longVal;

   @Inject
   public ClassA(@Named("some_str_val" String strVal, @Named("some_long_val") Long longVal)) {
       stringVal = strVal;
       longVal = longVal;
   }
}
```

I am not sure how to bind based on the annotation value.

```
class MyConfigModule extends AbstractModule {
    ConfigurationProvider configProvider;
    MyConfigModule(ConfigurationProvider configProvider) {
       configProvider = configProvider;
    }

    public void configure() {
       // Here, I would want to bind String annotated with Named to getString(annotation.value), but not sure how to do that
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
bind(String.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("property.name")).toInstance(configProvider.getString("property.name"));
```

which you can get fancy with or just manually add each property you expect to be in there.  If your `configProvider` can iterate through fields, it might be easier.